# Why if I raise my hand over the water while being underwater, my whole body goes down?

Tags: water, free-body-diagram, fluid-statics

Another weird question, I know, and may sound simple but I'm now trying to see why a lot of the things that we usually do without thinking, have some sense in physics, like this one.

Let's say you are in a deep pool, and you are covered with water entirely but, you raise your hand above the water, what happens in the water is that your body actually goes down and sinks. Why is that? Like why by putting some parts of our body outside of the water level makes us to go down in the water? I know it may be simple but I want to know, is it because we are like "lifting" in some sense, our own arm, so it makes us to go down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Archimedes' principle** can be used to explain this. When the arms are removed from the water, the buoyant force, which is proportional to the submerged volume, decreases. As a result, the balance of forces is changed in favor of the forces that push the object toward sinking.